# User reputation leagues broken?

Tags: bug, reputation, users-page

It looks to me as if the user reputation leagues are broken. To access them, one would go to the [user list](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users) and hit the link labelled "*weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues*" at the bottom.

Is that something that should already work at this point in time, or only once the Arduino SE community becomes a permanent one?

Comment: I think it's just caching... seriously though, I don't think it has data right now, as [softwarerecs.se]'s reputation leagues are up... so maybe wait a day/days/week?

Comment: The link is now there!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The link was always there, it just doesn't work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reputation leagues are now up and running.

http://stackexchange.com/leagues/288/week/arduino/

Answer (score 0):

Private beta is not the best time to concentrate on reputation and other competitive things. They are meant to build a critical mass of questions, answers, and users with a bit of experience in the site. I would imagine that the leagues won't start until public beta. As far as I know, we've only been in public beta a few hours, so I would give it a bit more time.

<strike>When they do start, though, they should be at http://stackexchange.com/leagues/272.</strike>

Edit: The link is now there at the bottom of [the Users page](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users). It goes to http://stackexchange.com/leagues/288/week/arduino, which does not currently exist.

Comment: Of course, those things are not very relevant, neither now nor later. This was not meant as a complaint, but rather I simply wanted to bring it to everyone's attention (or more correctly the people taking care of those matters) to ensure that once this community becomes permanent, it is fixed to prevent others from "real" complaints. And yes: We are officially in public beta since a few hours.